# How to call a SOAP function to send Drupal user data to a SOAP server?

Tags: rules, services

I'm trying to send user data to a remote SOAP server with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. I have installed the `wsclient_soap` module (a sub-module of the [Web service client](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient) module) and put in the URL for the WSDL file.  It seems to work as I get a few of the data types back on the Drupal end.

What I do not see, is a way to use the SOAP "operation" to send the values of a Drupal user back to the SOAP server.

Has anyone had any luck sending this type of data to a *remote* SOAP server?

Here is the code for my php evaluation I'm using to test:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://something.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
syslog(1, print_r($client->__getFunctions(), TRUE)); //this shows the correct function
$newuser = array(
     'email' => 'test@test.com',
     'phone' => '+33 06 12 34 56 78',
);
$client->__soapCall("availableFunctionFromGetFunctions", $newuser);
syslog(1, print_r($client->__getLastRequest(), TRUE));
syslog(1, print_r($client->__getLastResponse(), TRUE));
```

For the available functions, when printed to syslog, it shows the one I want with THREE variables, the two I want to send and one called "authentication".  The documentation I was given does not say what the value of authentication is supposed to be, so I have a feeling the "error" that is being thrown when I act out the rule is caused by this.

I will update as I get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you use the wsclient SOAP binding but your code doesn't use it. Instead, your code uses a direct query to the PHP SOAP interface.

[This thread](https://drupal.org/node/1956822) discusses the difference between the two binding and which one is preferrable.

From the module's readme file:

- You can create web service descriptions in code, see for example
  [wsclient_examples.module](http://drupalcode.org/project/wsclient.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/wsclient_examples/wsclient_examples.module)
- You can easily invoke web services by loading the description and executing
  an operation (the operation name can be used a dynamic method name):

  ```
  $service = wsclient_service_load('google');  
  $result = $service->translate('Hallo Welt', 'de|en');
  ```